# Firestore check if array in specific document contains a value

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to check if the array "devices" which is in the document "SOjTxEjMwb71isiiPnR8" contains the value "AE0EBAFA-1560-404B-A3DA". I just want to know this specific array in the specific document. Because it can be that the same value in the same array occurs in another document. How do I have to do this in Swift? Thanks a lot for your help.

[image: Firestore Image]

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`array-contains` operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), which in Swift looks like this:

```
devicesRefRef
  .whereField("devices", arrayContains: "AE0EBAFA-1560-404B-A3DA")
```

You can then [get the results once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) or [listen for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). You'll note that all links I provide are to the relevant sections of the documentation, so I recommend spending some time there.